# How do I stop HTML5 audio from playing even when removed from the DOM in iPad iOS7

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio, video

I'm having an issue where my audio/video slide based website will play every sound file, but not stop even if it was completely removed from the DOM. This only affects iOS7 on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pause the audio before removing it. I haven't tried it but it might be a work around what seems to be a bug.

```
document.getElementById('audioPlayerId').pause()
```

Comment: Does not work, it's as if focus is lost. When the element is removed it still plays.